# Where do I add HTML content into a block?

Tags: drupal, block

I have created a custom block, but there is no option to add content or any body part.

[image]

How do I add content to a block?

Comment: Hi, I saw your question in drupalanswers about login in a popup, I don't have any reputation there, so I'll try help with that question. I'm new to drupal 8 too, so, to solve that just put a link with a javascript to render a iframe (src='user/login') and with CSS create a correct style to your popup. Simple and efective - if u correct your question there I can provide more details. By the way, MilianG answer solve this question.

Comment: I will try your thoughts..then update to you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on block type. If you create a block in default type "Basic block" then you'll have one "Body" field for entering the content. But with Drupal 8 you also have ability to create custom block types. With custom block types (and your one is a custom one) you are responsible for adding body fields. So you don't see content field simply because that block type doesn't have one. You didn't add it.

Go to `Structure -> Block layout -> Custom block library (tab) -> Types (tab)`

... and on that page you can see all block types. You can manage them, add/remove fields etc.